# What does this box icon represent?

Tags: pc, destiny-2

[image: Box icon]

Since I started playing, I have seen this icon in the bottom right of my screen. Clicking it does nothing.

What does this icon represent?

I'll add a PC tag, as I'm playing on PC, and it could be related to that.

Comment: Looks like where the chat box would come up. Try pressing enter (assuming its the default chat key) and see what happens.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Yes, you're correct. It is the chat window! Please can you convert your comment into an answer, and I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the in game chat system which you can open by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.